# Pygame joystick only recognizes one gamepad at the same time (Raspberry Pi 3, Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gamepad

I'm really stuck with pygame. I programmed a quiz using two gamepads as buzzers.

It all worked fine on OS X, but when I want to run it on my Raspberry Pi 3 pygame only recognizes one of the two gamepads at the same time. Individually they are recognized just fine.

When both gamepads are plugged in
js = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1) returns
pygame.error: Invalid joystick device number